# For loop not reading list as expected past first iteration

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a for loop that reads lines of a text file sequentially, however it says my index is "out of range" past the first iteration of the loop.

Here is my test code that isn't doing what I expect:

```
guide = open("guide.txt", "r")
for x in range(10):
  print(guide.readlines()[x])
```

I expected it to print the first 10 lines of the text file, however it prints only the first line, then returns an error saying the list index is out of range.
(The text file is 2500 lines long, so it shouldn't be out of range)

The same error persists when "x" in line 3 is replaced with a constant, like 0 or 1.

What can I do so that my code will print the first 10 lines of the text file as expected?

Comment: `guide.readlines()` consumes the entire file `guide` and then leaves the file pointer at the end of the file. The next time you call it, there's nothing more to consume. Normally, you'd do something like `lines = guide.readlines()` outside of the loop, then `lines[x]` in the loop. (Well, _normally_ you'd probably iterate over the lines directly, e.g. something like `for line in lines[:10]`.)

Answer (score 3):

Here, don't readlines again, save it to a variable:

```py
with open("stack_guide.txt", "w") as guide:
    guide.write("""How do I ask a good question?
We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some guidelines to follow:
Make sure your question is on-topic and suitable for this site
Stack Overflow only accepts certain types of questions about programming and software development, and your question must be written in English.
If your question is not on-topic or is otherwise unsuitable for this site, then it will likely be closed.
Closure is not the end of the road for questions;
it is intended to be a temporary state until the question is revised to meet our requirements.
However, if you fail to do that, or it is impossible to do so, then the question will stay closed and will not be answered.
Since you're reading this page, hopefully you will post a suitable, on-topic question from the outset, thus eliminating the need for the closure and reopening process!
Search, and research
...""")
with open("stack_guide.txt", "r") as guide:
    lines = guide.readlines()
    for line in lines[:10]:
        print(line[:-1])
```

Output:

```
How do I ask a good question?
We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some guidelines to follow:
Make sure your question is on-topic and suitable for this site
Stack Overflow only accepts certain types of questions about programming and software development, and your question must be written in English.
If your question is not on-topic or is otherwise unsuitable for this site, then it will likely be closed.
Closure is not the end of the road for questions;
it is intended to be a temporary state until the question is revised to meet our requirements.
However, if you fail to do that, or it is impossible to do so, then the question will stay closed and will not be answered.
Since you're reading this page, hopefully you will post a suitable, on-topic question from the outset, thus eliminating the need for the closure and reopening process!
Search, and research
```